# Doing 1 if code with 2 different condition variables... Or something like this

Tags: php, arrays, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I wanted to make function with this possible argument:s

- `leFunction ((string) $type,(string) $data)` , this was simple, switch defining $return by given type (doing whatever switch can possibly do with $data). Eg I can send year 1865 as $data and if $type is "fromYear" and $data is_numeric, it'll do whatever it's supposed to do.
- `leFunction ((string) $type,(array) $data)` , this is where it gets tricky. Idea was that with this second option I can pass same args as `("fromYear", array("year" => 1865, ....) )` then check if `is_numeric($data["year"])` and continue with same code.

But when I combined both pieces together I got this not so great if:

```
if (is_numeric($data) || (is_array($data) && isset($data["year"])))
```

Then I replaced second part with function from parent obj :

```
if (is_numeric($data) || is_numeric($this->setIfGet("year", $data)))
```

func:

```
/**
     * @param $needle string key
     * @param $haystack array source
     * @param bool $null make true if value of $needle could be null
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function setIfGet($needle, $haystack, $null = false)
    {
        return (isset($haystack[$needle])) ? $haystack[$needle] : ($null) ? (array_key_exists($needle, $haystack) ? $haystack[$needle] : false): false;
    }
```

But here's the problem: If I want to echo year from $data argument I need to do

```
if (...) {
   echo $data;
    ...
}
```

but it wont work if $data was array and year which I want to echo is in

```
$data["year"];
```

How can I get it work for both cases for 1 echo.

Comment: read it twice, don't know what you are asking. i think i understand everything up to "But here's the problem ..."

Comment: Dagon, I edited my Q, is it understandable now?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my own question:

```
if (is_numeric($newData = $data) || is_numeric($newData = self::setIfGet("year", $data))){
    echo $newData;
```